# Mysql error 093

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error, 
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /storage/h14/202/1552202/public_html/signup.php on line 38.
What's wrong with this? I can't see it.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');

        $query = $db->prepare(" INSERT INTO Accounts(Usernames, Passwords) VALUES (:username ,". sha1(":password") .")");

        $query->bindParam("username", $username);

        $query->bindParam("password", $password);

        if($query->execute()){

            echo "<center>Account made</center>";

        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sha1 is not secure

Comment: The SQL text doesn't contain a `:password` placeholder. Echo out the SQL text and you will see what is happening... the `sha1` function call is consuming the string argument.. and the return from the function is being included in the SQL text.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sha1() like that.

First, don't use sha1. Use sha2/sha256. And actually you should also use hmac. PHP has a pretty good password hashing facility. Look into it! But that's not your question...

Second, at the time you're building your query, you're calculating the sha1() of the string literal ":password" and thus it is no longer a placeholder in your query. You need to take the sha1() of your password outside of your query string and pass the result as an argument.

Like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['Password']);
    try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');

    $query = $db->prepare(" INSERT INTO Accounts(Usernames, Passwords) VALUES (:username , :password )");

    $query->bindParam("username", $username);

    $query->bindParam("password", $password);

    if($query->execute()){

        echo "<center>Account made</center>";

    } else {
        echo "Er is een fout opgetreden";
    }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```